# Simpler validation framework for SWT/JFace than JFace DataBinding

Tags: swt, validation, jface

Is there a simpler-to-use validation framework for SWT and JFace than JFace DataBinding? I would like to simply attach validators to controls, and say on which events they should be invoked.

Comment: try RCPTool box.
You can find it here <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6089893/java-swt-user-input-validation>